# how to save data in a listView and scroll position while navigating between activities

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, savestate

I have an `Activity` that extends a `ListActivity` , in `onCreate` method i set the `contentView` and call an `AsyncTask` to load data and the list get filled as I want, the problem is when I check for example the detail activity and want go back the the `listView`: I get the `onCreate` method executed, data are loaded again and the `listView` is scrolled to the top loosing my previous position.
What I want to achieve is something like google gmail app for example: the list view get loaded once and the scroll position is saved.

I've looked so much over here and I tried many solutions but none is working.

What is the best way to achieve this scenario?

my activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    new LoadEvents().execute();
}
```

my asyncTask :

```
class LoadEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(AgendaIConstantes.URL_EVENTS, "GET", params);

                ......Processing 

                    eventList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapterRes = getListAdapter();
                if(adapterRes == null){
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Home.this, eventList,R.layout.list_item, 
                            new String[] { .....},
                            new int[] { .....});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? It may be worthwhile posting your code here (the relevant part of it). When you go back to an `Activity` that was only paused `onCreate` shouldn't be executed AFAIK, only `onResume`, so there may be something wrong with you `Activity` lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not execute your loading task every call of `onCreate` method. You can use either boolean flag in your activity or save state using [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

By the way, calling `getListAdapter` in `onPostExecute` is not very ok method and your null checking shows it.